# jQuery Sortable Tables, with adjoining rows?

Tags: jquery

I have a table. This table has a header, and footer. It has several columns, some of those columns relay numeric data. I want the end user to be able to click on a column header/footer to be able to sort the rows in the table based on that column. Simply enough with jQuery...

However, there is a hiccup. Some of those sortable rows have an adjoining row directly below it with some notes. I want it so that when the table is sorted, the complementary row sticks around with it's parent row.

Does something like this exist for jQuery?

[image: table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the class name set by the [`cssChildRow` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#csschildrow) - default is `tablesorter-childRow`.  Demo links available on that page.